# Shimano RT66 Rotors on Tektro Auriga

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I'm thinking of changing my original Tektro Polygon rotors to Shimano RT66 rotors. Both use 6 bolts and 160mm size. Is this will be fine with my Tektro Auriga brakes? And will changing the rotors cause significant difference?

Comment: ^ This should be an answer.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm pretty sure if the rotors are in the same size it'll be fine. What I really wanna know is will this make a significant differences on brakings. I just wanna know so I won't spend it for nothing.

Comment: Sorry, there was a useful comment above mine which was better as an answer.

Comment: I can't see 'em. Looks like have been deleted

Comment: @Emyr: I've posted the comment as an answer below!

Answer (score 2):

You'll just have to make sure that the rotors match the type of brake pads you use. Shimano mark their rotors for 'resin pads only' and the like! –

Comment: RT66 rotors are compatible with metal ceramic pads that Tektro use.

Comment: There should be no problem then. Make sure to tighten the screws on the rotor to the right specification (use a torque wrench!) and re-check after a short ride.